# Excel How to replace characters for private reason

Tags: excel, vba, replace, formula, hidden

For example cell,

A1 value is How are you!

A2 value is Hello Good Morning

I want to use some formula to make the results like this.

Result:

H** a** y***

H**** G*** M******

Would you mind letting me know are there have any suggestions on this case.
Thank you.

Comment: Use substitute() possibly.

Comment: Do you really want the letters to be _replaced by *_ - or do you want them to be _displayed as *_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't think of a formula, but this function should do it:

```
Public Function Masker(pString As String) As String
    
    Dim words As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    words = Split(pString, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
        words(i) = Left(words(i), 1) & String(Len(words(i)) - 1, "*")
    Next i
    
    Masker = Join(words, " ")
    
End Function
```